# Edit (another) file in the same directory without changing cwd

Tags: file

It needs to support completion.

An example use case would be: I'm on a given project (so a certain cwd) but need to update one of my Vim files. If they are already opened so navigate buffers or navigate them using MRU.

But often if I need another Vim file I used type `mc` to switch the cwd then `:e filename`. Then need to switch back.

It is also confusing because git folder changes when this happens.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution! I believe it would be helpful to others if you could describe your use case. I suppose an example would be helpful.

Comment: I am surprised you haven't encounter this yourself every hour on average

Comment: I'm using [vim-rooter](https://github.com/airblade/vim-rooter) that automatically change the cwd and fuzzy file engine like [vim-clap](https://github.com/liuchengxu/vim-clap) or [telescope](https://github.com/nvim-telescope/telescope.nvim). But I like very much your solution :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution doesn't involve tweaking `path` or a custom command (which isn't as scalable to other forms of `:edit`, like `:split`): I use a command-line mapping on `%%` to insert the directory. It goes like this:

```
cnoremap <expr> %% bk#filename#command_dir('%%')
```

where `bk#filename#command_dir` is an autoloaded function:

```
" Get the directory of a file
" - On Ex command lines, returns the directory of the file ('./' for new files)
" - On other command lines (/,?) returns the keymap used to trigger it
function! bk#filename#command_dir(keymap) abort
  let l:command_type = getcmdtype()
  if l:command_type isnot# ':'
    return a:keymap
  endif
  let l:dir = expand('%:h')
  if empty(l:dir)
    let l:dir = '.'
  endif
  return l:dir . (has('win64') || has('win32') || has('win32unix') ? '\' : '/')
endfunction
```

Now I type `:edit %%file`, `:vsplit %%`, or other variants when I need to (actually I have mappings that insert that automatically).

Comment: I like it. I have made it os independent because the / didnt bode well in windows.

Comment: @eyalkarni I've edited your edit to align better with my preferred style. Note that `has('win16')` is documented as always false, so I've also changed the condition a bit.

Answer (score 4):

This all is implemented long time ago by builtin command `:h :find` used along with option `:h 'path'`.

Namely:

```
set path=.
find FILENAME
```

which could be made a command.

Comment: right. I didn't know that!

Comment: On a second thought, it is quite not easy to make this into command because you need to specify correctly the completion function which I am not sure how to do. Abbreviation could work.

Answer (score 1):

The advantage here is that it filters only on files (not directories).
Also, it is a prepared command.

```
:com! -nargs=1 -bang -complete=customlist,EditFileComplete
        \ EditFile exec "edit<bang> ". expand("%:p:h")."/<args>"
:fun! EditFileComplete(A,L,P)
:    return map(filter(split(glob(expand("%:p:h").'/*'.(len(a:A)>1 ? a:A . "*" : '')), "\n"),'filewritable(v:val) != 2' ),'fnamemodify(v:val, ":t")' )
:endfun
```